# volley not work and get error in sample request

Tags: android, android-volley

hi i am new in android i tray to learn volley but i have problem
i don't know where i have problem i just get That didn't work! error
i use a sample volley request to learn
but i have getting just error
please help me and guide me where i have problem and what i should to do

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="res:"
        android:id="@+id/get_text"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.my;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get_text);
// ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        textView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }

    });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you provide error ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of volley

```
package com.yourpackage.volleyex;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.manciniprogramming.volleyex.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtShowTextResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtShowTextResult = findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyBrJ3ec9wTuS6L-xHkaXLU8BJbFsx_LZ9o";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    StringBuilder formattedResult = new StringBuilder();
                    JSONArray responseJSONArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                    for (int i = 0; i < responseJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                        formattedResult.append("\n" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name") + "=> \t" + responseJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).get("rating"));
                    }
                    txtShowTextResult.setText("List of Restaurants \n" + " Name" + "\t Rating \n" + formattedResult);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                txtShowTextResult.setText("An Error occured while making the request");
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```